# I need to extract the numbers in a text in an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have set of data in Excel sheet which has

```
D TUS Syrup 1.0ml
ENERGY MAX WHEY PROTEIN VANILLA Powder 40.0gm
ENERGY MAX WHEY PROTEIN VANILLA Powder 2.20gm
AZKALAX S Powder 10.30gm
AZPRO CHIA Seeds 200gm
```

need to converted into

```
1.0
40.0
2.20
10.30
200
```

but I applied the formula given here https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3329-excel-remove-first-last-n-characters.html
when I applied the code above

```
1
40
2
10
2
```

Comment: Look at the results compared to the original and edit the formula accordingly. You don't show exactly what you used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following UDF:

```
Function GetNum(cell)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d+(\.\d+)?"
        With .Execute(cell)
            GetNum = IIf(.Count > 0, .Item(0), CVErr(xlErrNA))
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = "D TUS Syrup 1.0ml"
print (re.findall("\d+", s))
```

the answer should be ['1', '0']